# Feeds CSV import error

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am trying to import a CSV from a url using the feeds module, I set everything up but when I start the import I get the following error:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: XXXXX StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in XXXXX/sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsConfigurable.inc on line 149

I have traced that error to this code, specifically the last line:

```
  public function getConfig() {
    $defaults = $this->configDefaults();
    return $this->config + $defaults;
  }
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

I removed the default mappings because they were for an RSS feed, with GUID title etc....Could this have something to do with it? Are those required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the alpha-4 or the current dev version of the feeds module? There have been a number of tickets discussing the same error condition you are having with node_save on import that coalesced around this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1213472) on Drupal.org with a resulting patch committed to the current dev branch. You can try downloading the current dev branch of feeds (almost a year older now than alpha-4) or applying the patch at #25 in the above issue if you don't want to accept all of the updates since the last alpha release.

Comment: thanks yea had found it was going to answer my own question if nobody else got to it. Thanks again